# What is the equivalent of BlobstoreLineInputReader for targeting Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce, pipeline

This is a python appengine question, mapreduce library 1.9.21 .

I have code writing lines to a blob in the local blobstore, then processing that using mapreduce BlobstoreLineInputReader.

Given that the files api is going away, I thought I'd retarget all my processing to cloud storage.

I would expect to find a class called GoogleCloudStorageLineInputReader, but there isn't anything like that. Is it hiding somewhere?

Is there something way I can use GoogleCloudStorageInputReader to read lines?

Another possibility is using GoogleCloudStorageRecordInputReader, but for that my input file needs to be in LevelDB format and I don't know how to create that except with a GoogleCloudStorageConsistentRecordOutputWriter, which I don't know how to use outside a mapreduce context. How might I do that?

Or am I doing this all wrong, is there some other possibility I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I attempted thinkjson's CloudStorageLineInputReader but had no success.

Then I found [this pull request](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce/pull/38)...which led me to [rbruyere's fork](https://github.com/rbruyere/appengine-mapreduce). Despite some linting issues (like the spelling on `GoolgeCloudStorageLineInputReader`), however at the bottom of the pull request it is mentioned that it works fine, and asks if the project needs to be taken over.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ryan pointed this link out to me (on the appengine google group), and I tried it.
But I was getting an odd mismatch between it and the Cloud Storage
client library; it's looking for "file_name" on GCSFileStat objects,
but in the library these only have "filename". I'm using version 1.9.21.0 of the cloud storage client library. I tried adding a property on GCSFileStat in common.py of that library, to map file_name to filename, and voila it all works. Good one!